# Sending SMS to/from a device from/to an android virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

Does anyone know how or if it's possible to send an SMS message to/from a physical device (android phone) to from/to a virtual device? And test the radio on the physical device or test the radio on the virtual device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't think it's possible to send an sms from a real device to a virtual device. But it is possible to send an sms to a virtual device if you open a telnet session to it.

```
telnet localhost <port> //you can find the port in the title of your virtual device
```

and after you've opened the telnet session you can send an sms with:

```
sms send <numberfrom> <themessage>
```

Comment: thanks; would you know how to test the radio on a device or on a virtual device? Or by sending a message via telnet (or port from avd to avd), does it use the radio interface layer (RIL)? that's what i'm really trying to get to.

Comment: Is there a way to receive texts, similarly?